# How to re-authorize the OAuth Application 'Git Credential Manager'

Tags: git, github

I am part of an organization that uses SSO in Github. I don't have problem to access the repository through the web, it redirects me to SSO login and that's all.

The problem started when I logged-in first to my personal repository on GitHub through Git-Bash, I did some changes and then I wanted to do changes in a repository from my organization. When I run the below command, it wrote me that I need to **re-authorize the OAuth Application**, but I don't understand how:

```
$ git push --delete origin v0.1.3
remote: The `<my_company>' organization has enabled or enforced SAML SSO. To access
remote: this repository, you must re-authorize the OAuth Application `Git Credential Manager`.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/<my_company>/myproj.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

How can I re-authorize the login?

I tried to re-open Git-Bash but it wrote me the same error.

Comment: If you have "you must re-authorize the ... 'Visual Studio'", then you'll need to remove Visual Studio from your settings here https://github.com/settings/applications, as well as follow the steps below.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

My company just enabled SSO for my Github Org overnight so was getting the same error running `git pull`.  I fixed this with the following steps.

1. Open Credential Manager in Windows and delete the existing credential for github.com
2. Re-initialise the cred manager in git bash: `git config --global credential.helper manager-core`
3. Re-run `git pull` and follow the pop-up instructions to authenticate in a browser (which happened automatically for me with SSO).

After those steps git commands worked for me again.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by downloading a legacy version of Chromium browser and setting it to be default browser.  The redirect fails at the very end, but I was able to authenticate.

Comment: For others, be aware that there could be several Github entries in the Windows Credential Manager.  Gotta catch 'em all, I guess.

Comment: In my case I tried using Personal Access Token but it didn't work. I had to re-login via browser.

Comment: I skipped step 2 and it still worked.

Comment: Instead of step 2, I needed to run `git credential-manager configure`

Comment: @JacobFoshee ah! that did it! I had two entries so was stumped why the above wouldn't work. Thank you both!

Comment: I have multiple GitHub credentials, including those from GitHub Desktop. Deleting only the `git:https//github.com` entry solved the issue for me

Answer (score 75):

I used the Github cli by running the following in the terminal

```
gh auth login
```

which then prompted me to [re-authenticate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CXAE.png), and I was able to.

If you do not have the CLI (Command Line Interface) currently installed, you can visit https://cli.github.com/ for more information. There is a download for Mac.

Comment: I saw this reauthorization error after my organization enabled SSO for GitHub Enterprise.  This solution worked well for me.  When it was complete, I could use the `git` CLI again.  When this authN process was running, it prompted me for "GHE hostname".  I didn't know what to put, so I just entered "github.com".  That turned out to be what I needed.

Comment: This is the easiest and best way of fixing the issue.

Comment: Note that using `gh auth login` is technically separate from using git credential manager core for authorization.  It works, but it uses a different credential management solution (oauth token).

Answer (score 29):

For VSCode users or any other IDE you need to force GitHub to re-authorize the app!

1. Go to your settings on **GitHub.com -> Applications -> Authorized OAuth Apps** - https://github.com/settings/applications
2. Search for "GitHub for VSCode"
3. Choose "**Revoke**" from the "..." menu.

If you then sign out in VSCode and sign in again, you should be prompted to re-authorized.

Comment: solution didn't help

Comment: In vscode.
A simpler solution for me was to click the 'Accounts' side panel on the left, then sign out and sign back in.

Answer (score 19):

Delete git from "credential manager" window's application. Then pull on repo again. The sso authentication should automatically come up.

Comment: To clarify, on mac, you can go to the "Keychain Access" app and delete any `git:` login credentials to re-force the git credential manager core login for GitHub.

Answer (score 8):

For Visual Studio 2022, Click your profile icon, select *Account Settings* and then remove and re-add your GitHub credentials

Comment: thanks a lot!! simple & effective

Comment: This also works for Visual Studio 2019

Answer (score 6):

This works for me by revoking the current application in the Github Settings > Settings > [Applications](https://github.com/settings/applications) > Authorized OAuth Apps

and then try the `git pull` again.

Answer (score 1):

In my case Authorisation was revoked and access was given back.
Now, Organisation authorisation was missing.

To enable it back, Follow the steps
•

1. Github Profile
2. Settings
3. Developer Settings
4. Select Personal access token
5. Delete existing token and generate new token under
   Tokens (classic)
6. Copy the new token created.
7. Click on Configure SSO arrow under generated token. You will see your organisation and it might display Authorise.
8. Click on Authorise. It should turn into Deauthorise in red.

After all this step open your terminal or command line tool

run below commands
`brew install gh` (if gh is not installed)
`gh auth login`

Follow the instruction and select https if you already cloned using `https`.

That's it. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on a Mac. The solution was to re-authenticate with GitHub:

```
$(git config --global credential.helper) github login
```

Answer (score 0):

In Visual studio code, click on profile icon and signout of git. Then login to github, go to settings > Applications > Authorized Oauth Apps. Revoke "VS code" and "Windows Credentials Manager".

In Windows, search for "Credentials Manager" app and delete "git:".

Now clone freshly from VS code and terminal(git clone). Authorize from browser in github. Now, you will re-authorized in both VS Code and command line.