# GitHub re-authorize OAuth app but no apps show

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, oauth

I was working on a repo as a collaborator, making changes and all just fine. Then I got invited to the organization and now I can't push, pull or even clone repos because it says that the organization enabled SAML SSO authorization.

The entire log:

```
remote: The `blankforjobreasons' organization has enabled or enforced SAML SSO. To access
remote: this repository, you must re-authorize the OAuth Application `GitHub for VS Code`.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/blankforjobreasons/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I've looked up solutions that said I should unauthorize GitHub for VS Code and get the prompt again, but when I go to my settings there are no OAuth apps to unauthorize. I can only manually add an OAuth app.

[image]

I've tried cloning the repo to another folder (get the same error), rebooting, logging out of my account and logging back in. Nothing seems to work.

I'm now considering reinstalling VS Code and the last resort would be to exit the organization an request a new invite, but this would prompt a series of in-house steps that are a bit long. Is there any way to do this that is simpler?

Edit1: Tried everything [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66475833/how-to-re-authorize-the-oauth-application-git-credential-manager?rq=2), didn't work (probably because I'm on macOS).

Answer (score 2):

How this got fixed:

Install the [GitHub cli](https://cli.github.com/)

Run `gh auth login`

You will be prompted to login to your GitHub account

Done!

Comment: I followed this approach and it also worked for me.